Oracle 11g, unable to drop user
I was unable to drop a user due to a strange error and I could not fix it, this is my log:
SQL> SELECT s.sid, s.serial#, s.status, p.spid FROM v$session s, v$process p WHERE s.username = 'GGATE' AND p.addr(+) = s.paddr;

no rows selected

SQL> drop user ggate cascade;
drop user ggate cascade
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-04045: errors during recompilation/revalidation of GGATE.DDLREPLICATION
ORA-04067: not executed, package body "GGATE.DDLREPLICATION" does not exist
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called:
"GGATE.DDLREPLICATION"
ORA-06512: at line 1342
ORA-04067: not executed, package body "GGATE.DDLREPLICATION" does not exist
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called:
"GGATE.DDLREPLICATION"
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called:
"GGATE.DDLREPLICATION"
ORA-06512: at line 1203
ORA-04045: errors during recompilation/revalidation of GGATE.DDLREPLICATION
ORA-04067: not executed, package body "GGATE.DDLREPLICATION" does not exist
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called:
"GGATE.DDLREPLICATION"
ORA-06512: at line 1342
ORA-04067: not executed, package body "GGATE.DDLREPLICATION" does not exist
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called:
"GGATE.DDLREPLICATION"
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called:
"GGATE.DDLREPLICATION"
ORA-04045: errors during recompilation/revalidation of GGATE.DDLREPLICATION
ORA-04067: not executed, package body "GGATE.DDLREPLICATION" does not exist
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called:
"GGATE.DDLREPLICATION"
ORA-06512: at line 1342
ORA-04067: not executed, package body "GGATE.DDLREPLICATION" does not exist
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called:
"GGATE.DDLREPLICATION"
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called:
"GGATE.DDLREPLICATION"

I also tried to drop package GGATE.DDLREPLICATION but it failed as well, please help to share me an advice.

Are you following the process for uninstalling Oracle GoldenGate, or just dropping that use independently? See also support document 1684716.1.

I did not know about this, thank you for the links, will try.
Regards
